# DataTable that is dynamically generated to be displayed in listview

Tags: listview, datatable, collectionview, maui

I doing a project in Maui.  I dynamically generate a datatable of which the column names are derived from a datafile that I read in runtime.  As such, I cannot do a datatemplate and am having trouble in displaying this datatable.  Any help is most welcome.  Please help me to display a datatable in a generic way equivalent to the wpf datagrid were we can just send the datatable.AsDataView to the itemsSource and the datagrid takes care of automatically generating the columns and all data binding.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Your question is incredibly vague and broad and contains no actual detail or specifics about what you are doing.